# Want to make an entry on datebase when some body likes my page embeded on my site

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I want to make an entry on database when somebody likes my page embeded on my site.
Language is php. Can `onclick` function work? Please suggest.

Comment: You need to add more information about how people embed your page (using what technology) and where

Comment: page is embeded via facebook social plugin. Just want that when a particular person likes it a new button appears below it for "Proceed for next step" or when liked just made an entry in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when a user likes your facebook-page using the like-**box** plugin then I **personally** don't think you can,

But if you mean that a user likes a page of your site, on your site, using the like-**button** plugin, then:


From the [like-button official documentation page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) :

> **How do I know when a user clicks a Like button?**
>   
>   
> If you are using the XFBML version of the button, you can subscribe to the 'edge.create' event through [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe).

And from the [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe) documentation page:

> **Example**
>   
>   
> For example, suppose you want to record Likes in your database whenever a button is clicked:
>
> ```
> FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
>     function(response) {
>         alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
>     }
> );
> ```